# How to move a row's contents from one table to another based off cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to move a row's contents within Table1 (range A1:H24) to another Table2 (on a different sheet than Table1) based off the Table1's H-cell value.
Ex. If H24 = "Yes", paste entire row onto table2, delete from table 1.

The code deletes the data from Table1 and pastes it onto sheet2, but it pastes below the table getting lower with each time you run the module.

```vb
Sub Archive()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Inventory").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("H1:H" & J)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Yes" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Yes" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@medicinal_nut the code you mentioned is *VERY* similar to the code [here](https://ar.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3723-excel-move-row-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value.html?comment_id=13627&PageSpeed=noscript).
You could have copied the code better by not replacing the **I** in the original code with the **J** in your code.

```
Set xRg = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("H1:H" & J)
```

IMHO, the code is doing what it is supposed to be doing because of the **J=J+1**.
It just inserts 1 new row below the last inserted row in your Archive sheet, otherwise, it would just overwrite the last-copied row with the newly copied row, which would be quite a waste, IMHO.
May be I don't understand your question, in which case, please state your question clearer. Or perhaps, you may be able to find a solution which might meet your needs, on the web page that I mentioned in the first line.

**Edited 1 day later on 18JUL2021: to provide more understandable code for OP**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Archive()
Dim HColumnRows As Range
Dim InventoryUsedRows As Long
Dim ArchiveUsedRows As Long
Dim HColumnCurrentRow As Long
    InventoryUsedRows = Worksheets("Inventory").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'ArchiveUsedRows can be directly manipulated here to set pasting point
    ArchiveUsedRows = Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ArchiveUsedRows = 1 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then ArchiveUsedRows = 0
    End If
    
    Set HColumnRows = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("H1:H" & InventoryUsedRows)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For HColumnCurrentRow = 1 To HColumnRows.Count
        If CStr(HColumnRows(HColumnCurrentRow).Value) = "Yes" Then
        'ArchiveUsedRows+n <- n can be changed to reset pasting point                
        HColumnRows(HColumnCurrentRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & ArchiveUsedRows + 1)
            HColumnRows(HColumnCurrentRow).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(HColumnRows(HColumnCurrentRow).Value) = "Yes" Then
                HColumnCurrentRow = HColumnCurrentRow - 1
            End If
            'ArchiveUsedRows+n where n can be changed to reset pasting point
            ArchiveUsedRows = ArchiveUsedRows + 1
        End If
    Next HColumnCurrentRow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! Yes that is the code I used. Is there a way for me to reset where the program starts pasting from again? If I understand your answer correctly, then resetting the starting point of where data is pasted could be the resolution I am looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited original code for more understandable variable names. Use Watches to understand how code flows. Try to modify it. I don't know how you want to call the sub. If you want to call it from inside a loop, you can edit the sub to accept a parameter indicating where to paste the copied cell/or use a global variable. Since I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve/context, I can only give you a general answer. That said, this code is not really optimal though I don't like to judge. 1.It changed loop control variable. 2.Processed row by row while arrays would be preferable.